# Compile qemu-kvm, kvm - how?

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am using ubuntu 14.04 64 bits and am trying to build kvm - here is what i did according to many messages I saw on this same topic.

git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/virt/kvm/qemu-kvm.git
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --disable-werror --enable-debug

so far so good - everything works - now comes:

make

I get the following:

./qemu-options.texi:1453: unknown command `list'
./qemu-options.texi:1453: table requires an argument: the formatter for @item
./qemu-options.texi:1453: warning: @table has text but no @item
make: *** [qemu-doc.html] Error 1

I want to build kvm too - anyone can help?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to build qemu-kvm? Is `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm` not sufficient?

Comment: @saiarcot895 This is a guess, but there are some patches in the git version that enable certain hardware configurations to use vfio to do vga-passthrough.

Answer (score 0):

KVM is in [Official Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kvm&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all). you can install it by simple commands without difficult compilation methods.

```
sudo apt-get install kvm qemu-kvm
```